# OAuth 2.0 authentication SSL

Tags: oauth-2.0

Is there any way to locally use OAuth 2.0 without SSL ? I tried to execute it in my localserver. but it says, I need SSL to perfome actions with Oauth 2.0.

> Error: it was not possible to open the OAuth access token URL: establishing SSL connections requires the OpenSSL extension enabled

Is there any way to use OAuth 2.0 without SSL ?

- Im using PHP Client Library for OAuth 2.0.

Comment: How about installing OpenSSL on your local test server …?

Answer (score 1):

The security of OAuth 2.0 is dependent on SSL, without it anyone could see the bearer token that belongs to the user and use it to pretend to be them. However if you need to turn ssl off for debugging purposes and your server is also written in PHP then I would try taking a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.disablesslchecks.php

Also SSL is dependent on the server, not the client.