# Google website sign in, get information, securely

Tags: php, google-plus, google-signin

I'm just trying to implement a simple Google Sign In feature on my website.

But so far all of the tutorials I have followed have not worked.

[Google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) I have followed this to the end, downloaded the api, do not fully understand how to use it. I kept trying to figure it out but, code that was working previously is not working now (giving me a 500 server error). Maybe I exceeded the daily limitation or something?

[Youtube tutorial 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-65R420rIUA) Flat out didn't work, the php file gave a 500 server error.

[Youtube tutorial 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxa581kKBNg) Didn't work. Didn't spend much time on this one because it's probably not compatible due to age.

What I have done and setup

1. Made a project at Google Developers Console
2. Sign in, Select your account
3. Displayed account information in Console(via JavaScript)
4. Sent `POST['idtoken']` to backend(PHP) and displayed results in console

What I need to do

1. Basically just securely get the users information (username+email) and verify that they are who they say they are.

I have read many of the articles [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) but it seems to just get further and further away from what I'm trying to do. Just trying to sign a user in securely.

Information, links, tips, anything is greatly appreciated.

Here's my code. Also I have downloaded a zip folder from [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) and put it into my htdocs folder that is accessed by localhost. I removed the ClientID and ClientSecret for Security.

SignFrontEnd.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<MYClientID>">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>    

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
      var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
      console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
      console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
      console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());   

      var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // xhr.open('POST', 'https://yourbackend.example.com/tokensignin');
      xhr.open('POST', '/google-api-php-client-1-master/Dreolo/SignBackEnd.php');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhr.onload = function() {
        // console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
        console.log('ResponseFromServer: ' + xhr.responseText);
      };
      xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
    }    
  </script>

  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

  <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
  <script>
    function signOut() {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log('User signed out.');
      });
    }
  </script>   
  <br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

SignBackEnd.php

```
    <?php
    require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src/Google/autoload.php');
    session_start();
    $client_id = '<MYClientID>';
    $client_secret = '<MYClientSecret>';
    $redirect_uri = 'http://http://localhost:8888/google-api-php-client-1-master/Dreolo/SignFrontEnd.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->setScopes('email');
    // $client->setScopes('profile');
    // $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

    /************************************************
      If we're logging out we just need to clear our
      local access token in this case
     ************************************************/
    if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
      unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    /************************************************
      If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow,
      we need to exchange that with the authenticate()
      function. We store the resultant access token
      bundle in the session, and redirect to ourself.
     ************************************************/
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
      $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    /************************************************
      If we have an access token, we can make
      requests, else we generate an authentication URL.
     ************************************************/
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    } else {
      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    }

    /************************************************
      If we're signed in we can go ahead and retrieve
      the ID token, which is part of the bundle of
      data that is exchange in the authenticate step
      - we only need to do a network call if we have
      to retrieve the Google certificate to verify it,
      and that can be cached.
     ************************************************/
    if($client->getAccessToken()){
      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
      $token_data = $client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
    }

    if (isset($token_data)) {
      echo print_r($token_data);
    }   

    echo 'working';

?>
```

Comment: Does nobody know anything else about this? I'm not finding much information on it online.

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate set up?

Comment: @Eddy I do not, is it required?

Comment: yes, OAuth won't work without SSL - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472613/oauth-2-0-authentication-ssl

Comment: are you sure this code works?i did the same it didnt work

Comment: sign out is working as it should but when i sign in , console doesn't show any output